# How can I access Bootstrap-select from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to submit a bootstrap-select and access it from a PHP file but all I'm getting is "Undefined index" error.
I tried to print

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and it gives me an empty array like: Array ( ) 
from:

```
<form method="post" id="multiple_select_form">
    <select name="framework" id="framework" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
        <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
        <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
        <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
    </select><br />
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_framework" id="hidden_framework" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#framework').change(function() {
    $('#hidden_framework').val($('#framework').val());
    });
$('#multiple_select_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($('#framework').val() != '') {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "insert.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data) {                        
                    $('#hidden_framework').val('');
                    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '');
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        } else {
            alert("Please select framework");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["framework"];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $_POST["hidden_framework"];
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: try `isset` in your `insert.php` page

Comment: What does alert(form_data); show you?

Comment: alert(form_data) shows:     1<br />Laravel,Codeigniter,ZendArray
    (
        [framework] => Zend
        [hidden_framework] => Laravel,Codeigniter,Zend
    )

Comment: You have posted your form via ajax and you got the result in your success block. So, Where did you get "Undefined index" error? @RidowanAhmed

Comment: when I load the insert.php, it gives me error

Comment: Is there different behavior when you select just 1 item vs. 2 or 3 from the select list ?  It looks like the value for framework will be a value for 1 item and an array for multiple, at least that is what Fiddle shows.

Answer (score 0):

when you send form data via ajax check the result in browser console, this is the only way. what you do is open insert.php , that is another new empty request.
in success function you make console.log(data) , this will print the result in the browser console.